# How to change a Value in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

%a = add <6 x i3> ,

I want to write a pass for type legalization.

```
for (auto &block : function) {
    std::vector<BinaryOperator *> binInstsToErase;
    for (auto &inst : block) {
      BinaryOperator * binaryOpInst = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&inst);
    Value * vector1 = inst.getOperand(0);
    Value * vector2 = inst.getOperand(1);
```

Currently, The vector1 and vector2 is 18bits long(numofElem(6)*elementsize(3)). First, I want to widen the vector1 and vector2 from <6 x i3> to <8 x i3>, which means the number of the element is legal. However, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: one way you can do is create a new value <8 x i3> and extract elements from <6 x i3> and insert it into <8 x i3>. or you can use shufflevector instruction.

Comment: Hi Chirag, I know how to extract elements.However, I don't know how to crate a new value <8 x i3 >.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConstantDataVector::get(LLVMContext &Context, ArrayRef< uint8_t > Elts)` to create a new vector first. You can use a `std::vector` as `Elts`. Then you can `push_back` origin values into the vector or extract and insert element to the new vector.
See http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantDataVector.html